# Trying to insert records unless value is 0

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have the following code which inserts multiple records into MySQL:

```
foreach ($_POST AS $input => $value) {
    if (stristr($input, 'percent_owner_')) {
        $memberID = str_replace('percent_owner_', '', $input);
        $data['memberID'][] = $memberID;
        $data['percentOwner'][] = $value;
    }
}
$total = array_sum($data['percentOwner']);

if ($total !=100) {
    $error = "Must total 100%.";
    include('./errors/shares_error.php');

} else {

    $c = count($data['memberID']);
    for ($i=0;$i<$c;$i++) {

        $asset_ID = $_GET['asset_ID'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO shares (asset_ID, member_ID, percent_owner) 
             VALUES ('$asset_ID', '{$data['memberID'][$i]}', '{$data['percentOwner'][$i]}')";
        $add_shares = $db->exec($query);
    }
}
```

If the 'percent_owner' value is 0, I don't want that record inserted. I attempted to put an `if` statement within the `for`, checking to see `if '{$data['percentOwner'][$i]}' !== 0` but was not able to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `if (intval($data['percentOwner'][$i]) !==0)`? It looks like you would be getting a string value as you had it, and that would fail the `!==` strict comparison against integer 0.

Comment: What did you try and in what way did it not work?

Comment: @Michael - I just tried what you suggested but it is still entering records when percent_owner = 0. Is there a way to do this with the sql statement?

Comment: @Progger See my answer below for what should work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the value `$data['percentOwner'][$i]` against 0 after casting it as an integer. It appears to be a string from the way you have produced the value above:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$c;$i++) {
  // Compare in if() against intval() of the value
  if (intval($data['percentOwner'][$i]) !== 0) {
    $asset_ID = $_GET['asset_ID'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO shares (asset_ID, member_ID, percent_owner) 
         VALUES ('$asset_ID', '{$data['memberID'][$i]}', '{$data['percentOwner'][$i]}')";
    $add_shares = $db->exec($query);
  }
}
```